# Typescript complaining about React useState setter `Argument of type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<never[]>>' is not assignable to parameter of

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Presume I have this react component

```
export default function Restaurants() {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchUsers().then(setUsers);
  })
  ...
```

and `User.ts` is

```
interface User { name: string; }
export function fetchUsers(): Promise<User[]> { return fetch(...).then(r => r.json()) }
```

TypeScript is throwing `Argument of type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<never[]>>' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: User[]) => void | PromiseLike<void>'. Types of parameters 'value' and 'value' are incompatible. Type 'IRestaurant[]' is not assignable to type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'. Type 'IRestaurant[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'. Type 'IRestaurant' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts`

I tried `const [users, setUsers]: [User[], Function] = useState([]);` but that also didn't solve the issue
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need TS to be able to infer *at the time that you call `useState`* what sort of value it will contain.

Since it's going to be an array of `User`s, use that for the generic:

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState<User[]>([]);
```

I'd also highly recommend not ignoring errors - unhandled rejections should be avoided whenever possible.

```
fetchUsers()
  .then(setUsers)
  .catch(handleErrors);
```

You also probably only want to fetch the users *once*, rather than every time the component mounts.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetchUsers()
    .then(setUsers)
    .catch(handleErrors);
}, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, it solved the issue.
The code provided above is just a partial one for representing the problem, I should mention that in the questions